# How can I retrieve the logical file name of the database from backup file

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, restore

I was looking into the steps of how to [Restore Database Backup using SQL Script (T-SQL)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/02/25/sql-server-restore-database-backup-using-sql-script-t-sql/). Here are the steps:

> Database `YourDB` has full backup `YourBackUpFile.bak`. It can be restored using following two steps:
>
> **Step 1:** Retrieve the logical file name of the database from the backup.
>
> ```
> RESTORE FILELISTONLY
> FROM DISK = 'D:BackUpYourBackUpFile.bak'
> GO
> ```
>
> **Step 2:** Use the values in the `LogicalName` column in the following step.
>
> ```
> ----Make Database to single user Mode
> ALTER DATABASE YourDB
> SET SINGLE_USER WITH
> ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
>
> ----Restore Database
> RESTORE DATABASE YourDB
> FROM DISK = 'D:BackUpYourBackUpFile.bak'
> WITH MOVE 'YourMDFLogicalName' TO 'D:DataYourMDFFile.mdf',
> MOVE 'YourLDFLogicalName' TO 'D:DataYourLDFFile.ldf'
> ```

I am just having problem on how to get the `YourMDFLogicalName` and `YourLDFLogicalName`.
Can any one help me with that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (LogicalName varchar(128),[PhysicalName] varchar(128), [Type] varchar, [FileGroupName] varchar(128), [Size] varchar(128), 
            [MaxSize] varchar(128), [FileId]varchar(128), [CreateLSN]varchar(128), [DropLSN]varchar(128), [UniqueId]varchar(128), [ReadOnlyLSN]varchar(128), [ReadWriteLSN]varchar(128), 
            [BackupSizeInBytes]varchar(128), [SourceBlockSize]varchar(128), [FileGroupId]varchar(128), [LogGroupGUID]varchar(128), [DifferentialBaseLSN]varchar(128), [DifferentialBaseGUID]varchar(128), [IsReadOnly]varchar(128), [IsPresent]varchar(128), [TDEThumbprint]varchar(128)
)
DECLARE @Path varchar(1000)='C:\SomePath\Base.bak'
DECLARE @LogicalNameData varchar(128),@LogicalNameLog varchar(128)
INSERT INTO @table
EXEC('
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM DISK=''' +@Path+ '''
   ')

   SET @LogicalNameData=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='D')
   SET @LogicalNameLog=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='L')

SELECT @LogicalNameData,@LogicalNameLog
```

**UPDATE**

According to [Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx):

> SQL Server files have two names:
>
> logical_file_name
>
> The logical_file_name is the name used to refer to the physical file
>   in all Transact-SQL statements. The logical file name must comply with
>   the rules for SQL Server identifiers and must be unique among logical
>   file names in the database.
>
> os_file_name
>
> The os_file_name is the name of the physical file including the
>   directory path. It must follow the rules for the operating system file
>   names.

Comment: The definition of RESTORE FILELISTONLY changes every so often, breaking this script.  Is there a way to do sort of a "SELECT INTO" or a "DECLARE CURSOR FOR"?

Answer (score 19):

logical_file_name: is the name used in Microsoft SQL Server when referencing the file. The name must be unique within the database and conform to the rules for identifiers. The name can be a character or Unicode constant, a regular identifier, or a delimited identifier.

From: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275464(v=sql.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275464%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Also, from Dalex's script, you can just run (without all the table logic):

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\MyBackups\Backup.bak'
```

Answer (score 11):

Updated version of script:

```sql
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    LogicalName varchar(128),
    [PhysicalName] varchar(128), 
    [Type] varchar, 
    [FileGroupName] varchar(128), 
    [Size] varchar(128),
    [MaxSize] varchar(128), 
    [FileId]varchar(128), 
    [CreateLSN]varchar(128), 
    [DropLSN]varchar(128), 
    [UniqueId]varchar(128), 
    [ReadOnlyLSN]varchar(128), 
    [ReadWriteLSN]varchar(128),
    [BackupSizeInBytes]varchar(128), 
    [SourceBlockSize]varchar(128), 
    [FileGroupId]varchar(128), 
    [LogGroupGUID]varchar(128), 
    [DifferentialBaseLSN]varchar(128), 
    [DifferentialBaseGUID]varchar(128), 
    [IsReadOnly]varchar(128), 
    [IsPresent]varchar(128), 
    [TDEThumbprint]varchar(128),
    [SnapshotUrl]varchar(128)
)
DECLARE @Path varchar(1000)='/path/to/backup.bak'
DECLARE @LogicalNameData varchar(128),@LogicalNameLog varchar(128)
INSERT INTO @table
EXEC('
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
   FROM DISK=''' +@Path+ '''
   ')

   SET @LogicalNameData=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='D')
   SET @LogicalNameLog=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='L')

SELECT @LogicalNameData,@LogicalNameLog
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have the original DB (from which the backup file was taken) then the easiest way to obtain its logical name is via :

```
use [original_db]
go
select file_name(1)
go
```

or with one T-SQL

```
> sqlcmd [connection parameters and credentials] -d [original_db] -Q "set nocount on; select file_name(1)" -h-1 -W
```

This would be the same logical_name you would use in the RESTORE command.

Comment: use [my_db_name]
go
select file_name(1), file_name(2)
go - I used this to also select the log file..

Comment: This is the best answer by far.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(1000)= N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\aaa.bak',
        @RestorePath NVARCHAR(max)='C:\'

DECLARE @Table TABLE
    (
      LogicalName VARCHAR(128) ,
      [PhysicalName] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [Type] VARCHAR ,
      [FileGroupName] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [Size] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [MaxSize] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [FileId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [CreateLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DropLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [UniqueId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [ReadOnlyLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [ReadWriteLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [BackupSizeInBytes] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [SourceBlockSize] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [FileGroupId] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [LogGroupGUID] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DifferentialBaseLSN] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [DifferentialBaseGUID] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [IsReadOnly] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [IsPresent] VARCHAR(128) ,
      [TDEThumbprint] VARCHAR(128)
    )

DECLARE @LogicalNameData VARCHAR(128) ,
    @LogicalNameLog VARCHAR(128)
INSERT  INTO @table
        EXEC ( '
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM DISK=''' + @Path + '''
   '
            )

DECLARE @restoreScript NVARCHAR(max)='RESTORE DATABASE [aaa] FROM DISK =''' + @Path + ''' WITH FILE = 1 '

SELECT  @restoreScript +=CHAR(10) + ' ,MOVE  ''' +  LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + 
        @RestorePath  + LogicalName + RIGHT(PhysicalName,4) + ''''
                         FROM   @Table
                         WHERE  Type = 'D'

 SELECT  @restoreScript += ' ,MOVE  ''' +  LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + @RestorePath  + LogicalName + '.ldf'''
                        FROM    @Table
                        WHERE   Type = 'L'

SET @restoreScript += ' , NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10 '
SELECT  @restoreScript
```

Comment: On SO, prefix code with 4 spaces to format it as code.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: this code " LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + @RestorePath  + LogicalName + '.ldf''" may not work. because Logical name can be different from physical name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making your changes manually, then you can find the corresponding names with the following query:

```
SELECT db.name AS [DB Name], mf.name AS [Full logical name],
CASE
  WHEN CHARINDEX('_', mf.name) > 0 THEN LEFT (mf.name, CHARINDEX('_', mf.name)-1)
  ELSE mf.name
END AS [Shortened logical name]
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases db ON db.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE mf.type_desc != 'LOG'
ORDER BY db.name;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While it seems reasonable that this code answers the question, it's generally better to include a little description as to what it's doing and how it addresses the specific problem, perhaps also the difference between this and other existing answers, to help readers in the future know which of the options is most suitable for them.

Answer (score 1):

**Try following code:**

```
DECLARE @BackUpPath nvarchar(2000)='D:\BackUpYourBackUpFile.bak'
EXEC('RESTORE FILELISTONLY  FROM DISK=''' +@BackUpPath+ '''  ')
```