# get data base name From backup file

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I develop a application by C# . a user can select Backup file from computer to restore data base .
backup file may have many data base .I want to show him or her the name of data base in my application to select which him or her want.

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089627/how-can-i-retrieve-the-logical-file-name-of-the-database-from-backup-file). you might want to do that through a stored procedure.

Comment: Please checkout this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.readfilelist.aspx